# How to wish a good working day to someone

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I want to wish to my colleague, like we do in italian, a good working day.

In my mind came the idea of using **Good Job**, but I don't think I'm right.

Instead, should I use **I wish you a good working day**? Is this used? Otherwise what could I say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UK English, there’s no colloquial way to do this. It’s not a sentiment that anyone ever expresses specifically with regard to the working day. You could just say “Have a good day”.

Comment: are there really no ways to express "have a good working day" in English ?

Comment: @Liiuc “Have a good working day” is perfectly grammatical, but it’s not colloquial, because no one ever says it. “Have a good day at work” would be OK if addressed to your spouse, but not to someone you are working with.

Comment: Suppose you car-pool with people who work in the same building as you, but who you don't normally see during the working day. I find it hard to imagine anyone saying *Have a good day at work!* to any of the others as they get out of the car and head off to their respective offices - they'd be much more likely to say something "facetiously despairing", such as *Once more unto the breach!*